# Material SearchBar Not Appearing

Tags: java, android, xml, search

For some reason, I cannot get the material searchbar to appear in my code. I want to make it appear on the load of NewImageActivity and then allow the user to enter a search term. The term will then be used to populate a GridView:

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".NewImageActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

**Activity**

```
public class NewImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SearchView mSearchView;
private RecyclerView mImageResults;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mImageResultsAdapter;
private ArrayList<Flicker> mPhotoArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_image);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: https://androidhub.intel.com/en/posts/nglauber/Android_Search.html try this approach

Comment: It is not displaying the searchbar...what should I have in the layout xml of the activity?